# How do I slow down a very simple animation in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I need to slow down the animation so it is not at lighting speed. How would I do this??

here is a section of my code...

```
animation_counter = 0

player_animation_left = ["player_sprites/player_left.png","player_sprites/player_left1.png", "player_sprites/player_left2.png",]

 if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player_surf = pygame.image.load(player_animation_left[animation_counter])
            player_surf = pygame.transform.rotozoom(player_surf, 0, 2.5)
            animation_counter = (animation_counter + 1) % len(player_animation_left)
            player_rect.x -= 4
```

I was expecting to see it switch between each image more slowly.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`pygame.time` documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html?highlight=time#module-pygame.time), you can use `pygame.time.delay()` or `pygame.time.wait()` to stop the process for a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with pygame but instead of relying on a timer you can play the same frame of the animation for multiple frames of your game by using integer divison. i.e.:

```
animation_counter = n//10
n = (n+1) % len(player_animation_left)*10
```

This would make each animation frame last 10x longer.

Comment: what is the value for N?

Comment: It should start at 0, you can make the 10 be whatever you want (10,100,1000) it will just delay the animation by that amount.

Comment: Hmmm. It doesn't animate anything at all.